# Запуская docker-compose.yml при инициализации и дальнейшем запуске контейнера, пишет что нет прав, как исправить?

Tags: docker, npm, docker-compose, dockerfile

при выполнении файла docker-compose.yml с таким содержанием вылазит в дальнейшем ошибка, говорящая за отсутствие прав на папку /.npm, как можно в данном конфигурационном файле указать после выполнения установки npm install, выдать права на папку ?
Пробовал в контексте entrypoint применить chown -R 1002:1002 /.npm &&, но результатов это не дало, так как вероятно начиная с "-c" выполняется "\ строка регламента действия".
Пожалуйста, скажите, какие будут рекомендации по решению проблемы, как поступать ?
Можно к примеру все этапы регламентированных действий по установке, вынести из docker-compose конфигурации в dockerfile, а docker-compose будет ссылаться на него ? И если можно, то как ?

**docker-compose.yml**

```
    version: "2.4"

services:
  frontend-build:
    image: node:buster-slim
    restart: "no"
    user: "${BUILD_USER-1000:1000}"
    shm_size: 4gb
    working_dir: /root
    mem_limit: "2100000000"
    ulimits:
      nproc: 655350
      nofile:
        soft: 102400
        hard: 102400
    environment:
      MALLOC_ARENA_MAX: 1
      NODE_DISABLE_COLORS: 1
      NODE_OPTIONS: "--max-old-space-size=2000 --v8-pool-size=1"
    volumes: ["./:/root:delegated"]
    entrypoint: [
        "/bin/bash",
        "-c",
        "\
        export &&\
        id &&\
        ulimit -a &&\
        npm install -g npm@7.19.0 &&\
        npm test &&\
        npm run build || (cat /home/node/.npm/_logs/* && false)",
]
```

**Результат:**

```
frontend-build_1  | declare -x HOME="/"
frontend-build_1  | declare -x HOSTNAME="947cd6da2ca7"
frontend-build_1  | declare -x MALLOC_ARENA_MAX="1"
frontend-build_1  | declare -x NODE_DISABLE_COLORS="1"
frontend-build_1  | declare -x NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=2000 --v8-pool-size=1"
frontend-build_1  | declare -x NODE_VERSION="16.3.0"
frontend-build_1  | declare -x OLDPWD
frontend-build_1  | declare -x PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
frontend-build_1  | declare -x PWD="/root"
frontend-build_1  | declare -x SHLVL="1"
frontend-build_1  | declare -x YARN_VERSION="1.22.5"
frontend-build_1  | uid=1002 gid=1002 groups=1002
frontend-build_1  | core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
frontend-build_1  | data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
frontend-build_1  | scheduling priority             (-e) 0
frontend-build_1  | file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
frontend-build_1  | pending signals                 (-i) 23499
frontend-build_1  | max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 16384
frontend-build_1  | max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
frontend-build_1  | open files                      (-n) 102400
frontend-build_1  | pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
frontend-build_1  | POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
frontend-build_1  | real-time priority              (-r) 0
frontend-build_1  | stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
frontend-build_1  | cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
frontend-build_1  | max user processes              (-u) 655350
frontend-build_1  | virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
frontend-build_1  | file locks                      (-x) unlimited
frontend-build_1  | npm ERR! code EACCES
frontend-build_1  | npm ERR! syscall mkdir
frontend-build_1  | npm ERR! path /.npm
frontend-build_1  | npm ERR! errno EACCES
frontend-build_1  | npm ERR!
frontend-build_1  | npm ERR! Your cache folder contains root-owned files, due to a bug in
frontend-build_1  | npm ERR! previous versions of npm which has since been addressed.
frontend-build_1  | npm ERR!
frontend-build_1  | npm ERR! To permanently fix this problem, please run:
frontend-build_1  | npm ERR!   sudo chown -R 1002:1002 "/.npm"
frontend-build_1  | cat: '/home/node/.npm/_logs/*': No such file or directory
frontend-build_1 exited with code 1
Aborting on container exit...
```